# Error summing values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I get the following error when trying to sum the values from a dictionary.  I expect to get the sum (i.e. 15), but an error is thrown instead.

Is this a bug?

IPython QtConsole 3.1.0
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)

```
d = {'1': 1, '2': 2 , '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5}

>>> sum(d.values())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-4babd535f17a> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(d.values())

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Seems that you have a integer variable with name `sum` in your code.for getting ride of that change that name or use `del sum` to delete that shallow copy of `sum` function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have named a variable `sum` in your code which points to an int so you are actually trying to call that not the `sum` function.  Just add a `del sum` then try the code again. 
A good example of why you should not shadow builtin function names.

```
In [24]: sum = 4    
In [25]: sum((1,2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a2ca1bd9c959> in <module>()
----> 1 sum((1,2))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable  
In [26]: del sum
In [27]: sum((1,2))
Out[27]: 3
```

Comment: I was testing some code snippets from the web and didn't even realize I clobbered my builtins.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries, it happens quite often.